# How to check the value based on the status in Karate Framework

Tags: karate

There are three columns in the data

Name   Age  Gender  ErrorCode
SA     15    M        Success
SR     20    F        Success

If status of the api is 200 only I should check the match response for Name , Age , Gender.

If status of the API is 400 I should check only the Error Code.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Read this: https://github.com/intuit/karate#conditional-logic

```
* def expected = responseStatus == 400 ? { err: 'code' } : { foo: 'bar' }
* match response contains expected
```